# How get javascript log using Selenium on NUnit test?

Tags: asp.net, selenium, nunit

I'm trying to retrive Javascript console logs from NUnit test on Visual studio using Selenium ChromeDriver but i get a null value on Logs.

I have tried the code below but it will give a Null point reference on "driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);". I'm using last version of ChromeDriver v75.

```
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.Warning);

var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");

var entries = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
foreach (var entry in entries) {
    Console.WriteLine(entry.ToString());
}
```

I think that there is an version problem between the Chrome version and the ChromeDriver on Visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment for workaround i downgrade he ChromeDriver to version 72 an now it's working correctly.